# Hidden space in layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have created a layout as shown in image below:

[image]

Now the problem its having so space between the image and the like/heart layout which i have highlighted in red line. I have tried a lot to remove it but the thing is it does not show the space in the graphical layout. But whenever i try to run the application the space always shown.

I don't understand where exactly this space is coming from. I have tried all the possible things.

Please help me out to remove the space.

Here is the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg_selector">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sp_color"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".9"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sp_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:background="@drawable/baby1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sp_profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello World" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sp_linh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_clk_hrts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp_imageHeart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/heart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sp_hearts"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="12"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sp_ll_like_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp_imageLike"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_like" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sp_likes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**bg_selector** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#EBEBEB" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" 
        android:color="@android:color/black" 
       />

</shape>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the layout_weight value of sp_linh linear layout. I think ".10" will be considered as ".1". So it occupies very little space at the bottom.

Comment: Would you like your heart/like bar to be exactly at the bottom of the screen? Or being just below the image with text is ok?

Comment: @Onik I want my heart/like exactly below the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

- For the outer (first) `LinearLayout`, set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
- Or add to that outer layout an empty element (like `Space`) as the last one, after the like bar, `@+id/sp_linh`, and give it enough weight to push up that bar.